# Optimizing using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So in a front end course I'm taking, it gives this example of how `setTimout()` allows the client to still interact with the page while it interprets the javascript.

To me it looks like it would still cause issues (even though I know it doesn't) . Why don't we put the `setTimeout()` inside of the for loop? Also, why does the `setTimout()` reference the function that it's inside?

```
let count = 1

function generateParagraphs() {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (let i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
        const newElement = document.createElement('p');
        newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + count;
        count = count + 1;

        fragment.appendChild(newElement);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(fragment);

    if (count < 20000) {
        setTimeout(generateParagraphs, 0);
    }
}

generateParagraphs();
```

Comment: Why do you think you **should** put it in a loop? Do you want it to spawn all the paragraphs 2 seconds from now, or 1 every 2 seconds for however long to loop goes?

Comment: Also, you aren't waiting any duration for your timeouts, is that what you intend?

Comment: @zero298 a 0 timeout still waits at least the next event loop iteration.

Comment: setTimeout defers execution and adds it to the queue in the event loop, and allows other instructions to process first, allowing the UI to be responsive.  500 DOM operations is minimal enough not to block the thread enough to be noticeable, so deferring each set of 500 operations and allowing other tasks to process in between allows for things to stay responsive

Comment: Doesn't your course answer these questions? Here it feels we would have to make the full lesson from scratch to you...